# React fetch() not working on mobile only

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fetch, jsx

I'm an intern assisting on developing a simple landing page for our company.  The main page is essentially a search bar, and as a user types if their query matches a credit union in our database, the name of that credit union is output below with a link to its page. Imagine a google-esque search bar.

This works great on desktop but for some reason, on mobile when a user types in a query, nothing comes up at all, even if they're typing something that most definitely exists in our database.

To see the site in action, it's http://mycuapp.com .

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<Search></Search>
<div id = "results-bar" class="hidden"></div>
```

and the JS:

```
handleTyping(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    var query = event.target.value;
    var url = "/search/" + query; 
    var i;
    if (query.length >= 3) {
        fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
        }).then((value) => {
                return value.json();
        }).then((Response)=>{
            var item = document.getElementById("results-bar");
            if(item.className=='hidden'){
                item.className = 'unhidden' ;
                clickedButton.value = 'hide';
            }
            for (i = 0; i < Response.payload.length; i++){
                var displayName = Response.payload[i].displayName;
                var cuURL = Response.payload[i].url;
                if(document.getElementById("results-bar").innerHTML.indexOf(displayName) == -1){ //not yet displayed in search results
                    var result = "<div class = 'result'><a href='" + cuURL + "'><p>" + displayName + "</p></a></div>";
                    document.getElementById("results-bar").innerHTML += result;
                }
                console.log(Response.payload[i].displayName);
            }
        });

    }
}


render() {
    return (
        <form className="" id="search-form">
            <input onKeyUp={this.handleTyping} type="text" autoComplete="off" name="query" placeholder="Search your credit union's name to download the mobile banking app."/>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, including any suggestions on how to debug the problem from an iPhone (bc when simulated with Chrome's developer tools there is no issue).

EDIT: Turns out the problem is the line "const data = new FormData(event.target);"  FormData is incompatible with Safari, or something.  Our lead programmer caught it.  Once we got rid of that line everything works great! Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Try adding polyfill and see if this fixes your problem: https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to use `Response` stream which is not fully supported on Mobile Safari. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Alternatively you can use fetch polyfill which is supported in Safari 6.1+
https://github.com/github/fetch

FormData: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
Is not compatible with Safari Mobile.